# Is it possible to port an Android application to Android Wear?

Tags: applications, android-wear

How can I port a native Android application to Android Wear OS? I know that this is not really possible, especially in the case of complex Android applications. What could be the main drawbacks of the porting process?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Please note that app development is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users and power users (who are not necessarily developers) solving their issues. Thus, while this community might explain the technicality of Android OS to your queries, development process is generally out of the scope of this community. For programming questions, you might want to try our sister site [so] (if you have the original source code) or [reverseengineering.se] (if you don't have the original source code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are so different, it would not be easy to emulate the items missing on the watch such as the keyboard, size of the screen.  And there are watch versions of some android apps.  I tried some, but it was a pointless pain act.

You can however, mirror almost any widget from the phone home screen to the watch.  I have been using [Wearable Widgets](https://wearablewidgets.com/)

> **Widgets you can wear:** Put virtually any home screen widget from your Android™ phone onto your Wear OS watch.
>
> Take a look at the home screen of your phone – you probably have a number of widgets that you refer to all the time. Now imagine how useful they would be if you could see them on your watch: weather, news, sports scores and much more, all at a glance without having to drag out your phone.
>
> Wearable Widgets creates a bridge from your phone to your watch for the widgets you already use. Thousands of Android apps support a watch-sized display right now, under the guise of widgets. You don't need to wait for developers to support smartwatches; get your apps on your wrist now. Get Wearable Widgets.

I am not associated with it, in any fashion.